# How to refresh the Gmail mailbox without logging back in with IMAP

Tags: python, imap

I need to read large amounts of email right as they come in but due to Gmails login rate limits I cant log in and log out each time to refresh the mailbox. Is there another way to do so?

Comment: The NOOP command is used to tel the server you’re ready for new information. Or if your library supports it and you have a stable internet connection the IDLE command allows the server to push you updates.

Comment: If you’re using imaplib, it doesn’t support idle but you can do something like sleep(60), then imalib.noop().